# how to handle big relational data

Tags: mysql, node.js, typeorm

I have a MySQL database. In one of the tables, I have a `json` column named `event`. The input type of the `event` is an array of the following:

```
{
 cam:{x:number,y:number,z:number},
 scn: {x:number,y:number,z:number},
 time: Date
}
```

It contains analytical data, one record may contain up to `20,000` elements inside the array. And for one product I might get up to `12,000` records. When I run my simple query of `select * from ABC where product_id=3` it takes up to 2-3 minutes to fetch this big data. If I perform some group or any other query it will take much more time. My question is how can I handle such big data? How do big companies manage it?

Comment: Don't use relational for data that are definitely noSql document data. Should probably look at MongoDB or other like that.

Comment: @Blag There is no hope for me in mysql then? any suggestion that might help me within the mysql.

Comment: Just to be sure, could you update your question with your table schema ? you speech of product_id, but I don't see where it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When storing files is an option and you really want to use a relational db than store the json as a .json file and read it with a filestream to get it. The path to the file could be stored in the column. Other than that please use something like mongodb or sqlite3

Answer (score 0):

As someone has already pointed out in the comments, a relational database isn't best suited for such data (assuming your schema of 'event' might change). However MySQL does provide a workaround by using generated columns and indexing them.

[You can read up on it here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html)

Apart from this, since your data does have a structure to it, You could use another table as well to store event data. Simply storing something as a JSON doesn't mean that data doesn't have a structure to it. You need to understand your data to understand what truly is best to store and process it.